# View's invalidate redraws previous texture also

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-custom-view, custom-view

I want to achieve something like this.

[image]

but instead of that, I'm getting something like this.

[image]

I'm using `invalidate` to redraw my custom view. But it is creating another view everytime the sides of polygon is changed. Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code.

**PolygonView.Java**

```
public class PolygonView extends View {

    public float polygonRadius;
    public int polygonSides;
    public int polygonColor;

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;
    public PolygonView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public PolygonView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public PolygonView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public PolygonView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        polygonColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.polygonColor);
        polygonSides = 5;

        if (attrs!=null){
            TypedArray typedArray = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.PolygonView,0,0);
            polygonColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.PolygonView_polygon_color,polygonColor);
            polygonRadius = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.PolygonView_polygon_radius,polygonRadius);
            polygonSides = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.PolygonView_polygon_sides,polygonSides);
        }

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(polygonColor);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        path = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        double angle = 2.0*Math.PI/polygonSides;
        int cx = getWidth()/2;
        int cy = getHeight()/2;
        path.moveTo(
                (float) (cx +polygonRadius*Math.cos(0.0)),
                (float) (cy +polygonRadius*Math.sin(0.0))
        );
        for(int i=1;i<=polygonSides;i++){
            path.lineTo(
                    (float) (cx + polygonRadius*Math.cos(angle*i)),
                    (float) (cy + polygonRadius*Math.sin(angle*i))
            );
        }

        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);

    }
}
```

**Fragment2.Java**

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


public Fragment2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_polygon, container, false);

    final PolygonView polygonView = v.findViewById(R.id.polygonView);
    SeekBar seekBarRadius = v.findViewById(R.id.seekBarRadius);
    SeekBar seekBarSides = v.findViewById(R.id.seekBarSides);

    seekBarSides.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            int p = progress/10;
            if(p<1){
                polygonView.polygonSides = 1;
            }else if (p>10){
                polygonView.polygonSides = 10;
            }
            else {
                polygonView.polygonSides = p;
            }

            polygonView.invalidate();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: dont call `path.lineTo` inside `onDraw` - just call `drawPath` only and move `lineTo` stuff to `setPolygonSides` method, also dont forget to call `Path#reset` method first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always mutating your path but never reset it. Inside `onDraw()` method [reset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#reset()) the `path` and only then apply new operations to it:

```
    public void onDraw() {
        path.reset();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: and inside `onDraw` only `Canvas#drawPath` should be called - setting the path should be done somewhere else

Comment: Agree with @pskink, that's an optimization that **should** be done, but that has not connection with the issue itself. Thanks.

Comment: that way OP will be forced to introduce some `setPolygonSides` method instead of ugly: `polygonView.polygonSides = p;
polygonView.invalidate();` but yes i agree it is an optimization not absolutely required

Comment: `setting the path should be done somewhere else` - where exactly? @pskink

Comment: as i said, inside `setPolygonSides` method

Comment: Yep, if OP decides to introduce `setPolygonSides()` method, then `path.reset()` should be moved there as well as path construction logics. Thus, as you said, `onDraw()` will be left with simple `canvas.drawPath()`. @pskink

Comment: what difference does it make setting a path in a method then in ondraw?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, move the code out of `onDraw()` method as much as possible. If you are able to interact with `path` **not** inside `onDraw()` - you should do that. Inside `onDraw()` should be done as few operations as possible. `onDraw()` is **not** guaranteed to be called once, thus you might end up wasting CPU cycles and potentially drop frames.